# What are these red-stemmed plants (probable weeds)

Tags: identification, weeds

Garden Context:
Sunny South-facing Garden in North London, UK. Appers not hugely cared-for in the last decade.

Border Context:
This photo is taken facing about North-North-East:
[image]

My experience:
Almost None! This is my First garden and I'm just learning the ropes.

---

I've started weeding through the over grown borders of the garden and left behind some plants I didn't recognise.

I *think* there are 2 of the same plant, with red stems.
What are they?
(Previous search attempts "UK Red stemmed weed")

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a neat way to create the post with the image initially as a thumbnail, then expanding out to full size on click?

Comment: yes, there is - let me check if I scan find it and I’ll get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely [Epilobium ciliatum](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/121176/epilobium-ciliatum/details) or less likely [Epilobium tetragonum](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/116937/i-epilobium-tetragonum-i/details)

Willowherb.

Also see:

- https://collections.tepapa.govt.nz/object/1567675
- http://luirig.altervista.org/schedenam/fnam.php?taxon=Epilobium+ciliatum