# What's this fairly generic looking plant (probable weed)

Tags: identification, weeds

Garden Context:
Sunny South-facing Garden in North London, UK. Appers not hugely cared-for in the last decade.

Border Context:
This photo is taken facing about North-North-East:
[image]

My experience:
Almost None! This is my First garden and I'm just learning the ropes.

---

I've started weeding through the over grown borders of the garden and left behind some plants I didn't recognise.

I vaguely reminds me of etoilated Pelargonia? But beyond that it looks like a pretty generic small plant.

What is it?

(No idea what sort of search terms to try.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: FYI, the plant in the background of the border photo is a (falling over) aquilegia.

Comment: Red-stemmed plant in the top right is asked about here: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/51983/what-are-these-red-stemmed-plants-probable-weeds

Comment: Hard to tell until it flowers; there are multiple types of plant with leaves like that. Perhaps a cranesbill of some kind?

Comment: @VinceBowdren it did indeed turn out to be a cranesbill / creeping geranium - something like Dragonheart. Do you want to make that an answer, to earn internet points?

Comment: that's very generous, but I suspect you did more work on getting the ID. You should answer yourself, providing a photo of it flowering; that would be a more useful answer than me just repeating my vague comment.

Comment: `I suspect you did more work on getting the ID` ... I mean ... I left it alone for several months and then google 'cranesbill' once it flowered :)  But sure - I'll put up photos next time it flowers.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this flowered into something closely resembling a "Dragonheart" Cranesbill / Creeping Geranium.

Photos will follow, in summer.